# Antd Treenode title and height css setting

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am using [Antd v4.2.4 Tree](https://ant.design/components/tree/#components-tree-demo-directory) (example: virtual scroll) from the link. I woulld like to use the virtual Scroll which can be used by setting "height" prop of the Tree. All is fine till here as in the example.

- I would like to apply some css to the scrollbar like both overflowX and Y should be enabled on hover in the container
- I would like have the Tree node show in only single line when the title is really big and not wrap it, if I use overflowX css, it doesn't work.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/virtual-scroll-ant-design-demo-015x4?file=/index.js)

**Update1:** I see when we set "height" prop to Tree a lot of Divs have the inline css elements so not sure how to override them.

May be there is something small here but I am unable to figure out

I want to have such a look for my TreeNode and when hovered on this container the scrollbar X and Y is visible to see the longer node title please advice
[image]

**update 2**

if the set following css I am able to get the title in single line, but the scroll-X behaves strange. i.e. the scoll-x gets hidden when the Tree height/contents are big and when ypu collapse all treenodes, it shows up

```
.ant-tree .ant-tree-treenode {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/virtual-scroll-ant-design-demo-vlf41?file=/index.css)

TIA